# Rails 5 - Scope with latest has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm creating a filtered table for my user model. I've created a few scopes to filter them. I'm :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoices

  scope :application_approved, -> { ... }
  scope :application_denied, -> { ... }
  scope :latest_invoice_paid, -> { ... }
  scope :latest_invoice_not_paid, -> { ... }

  def self.__self__
    self
  end
end
```

and in the controller:

```
def index
  filters = params[:statuses] || {}
  application_status = filters[:application_status].presence
  payments_status = filters[:payments_status].presence
  @vehicles = Vehicle.send(application_status || :__self__)
                     .send(payment_status || :__self__)
                     .paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
                     .order('created_at DESC')
end
```

All of the filters work in isolation, however when chained, filters that are not applied seem to cancel out the earlier filters.

For example, if I set the filter to only show users who have paid, it works. But if I set the filter to only show users who have been approved/unapproved, all users are returned all the time. It seems as though returning `self` when a filter is not applied just returns all of the users.

So, how can I skip the scope if a filter is not applied for it?

Comment: Not sure how to solve your problem. But I do want to point out that we have [Object#itself](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Object.html#method-i-itself) method (you can replace `:__self__` with `:itself`, not sure if it will change anything though). You should inspect the results step by step in rails console. Call [to_sql](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/to_sql) on the queries at each step to see what's changed.

Comment: Passing user input to `send` is dangerous! For example, if a malicious user requested with application_status = `delete_all`, then the app would execute `Vehicle.send("delete_all")`.

Comment: Are you calling `unscoped` or `unscope` within any of the named scopes? Those could potentially cause the problem you are describing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick, it also helps secure your *send* method. Since only whitelisted methods can be executed. The code below does the following:

1. First create a whitelist with the allowed keys and allowed values.
2. Get the `params[:statuses]` or if it doesn't exist create a new *Parameters* object.
3. Permit only the allowed keys.
4. Remove all key-value instances that don't have whitelisted values.
5. Convert the allowed parameters into a hash.
6. Reduce the resulting collection. Start with `Vehicle.all` and send the whitelisted methods (chaining them together). If a key or value isn't present, it won't be looped over so there is no need to call `:__self__`, or `:itself`.
7. Do the rest of your logic.

```
def index
  whitelist = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(
    application_status: %w[application_approved application_denied],
    payments_status: %w[latest_invoice_paid latest_invoice_not_paid],
  )

  filters = params[:statuses] || ActionController::Parameters.new

  @vehicles = 
    filters
    .permit(*whitelist.keys)
    .select { |key, value| whitelist[key].include?(value) }
    .to_h
    .reduce(Vehicle.all) { |vehicles, (_key, value)| vehicles.send(value) }
    .order(created_at: :desc)
    .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
end
```

**References:**

- [*ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess*](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html)
- [*ActionController::Parameters*](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) (*permit*, *select* and *to_h* can all be found here)
- [*Enumerable#reduce*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce)
- The [splat operator `*`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion) in `.permit(*whitelist.keys)`